# PHP is only submitting the last selection of a multi selection drop-down menu

Tags: php, html, forms

I am a newbie to PHP, and I really don't know what I am doing wrong or even if what I have done is correct, but it seems working, however only the drop-down menus aren't fully working.

The $SelectThree and $SelectFour only shows the last selection... for example if you picked DropDown Option A and B... only B will show in the email... i.e:

```
Name: name 
Number: number 
Date: 10/06/2014 
Select: DropdownA 
Select2: DropdownA 
Select3: Drop Down Option B 
Select4: Drop Down Option B 
Radio: female 
Checkbox: OptionB 
Switch: On 
Email: example@example.com 
Message: message
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
       session_start();
       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
          ob_start();
          if(isset(
             $_REQUEST['name'],
             $_REQUEST['email'],
             $_REQUEST['message'],
             $_REQUEST['number'],
             $_REQUEST['date'],
             $_REQUEST['select'],
             $_REQUEST['selectTwo'],
             $_REQUEST['selectThree'],
             $_REQUEST['selectFour'],
             $_REQUEST['radio'],
             $_REQUEST['checkbox'],
             $_REQUEST['switch'],
             $_REQUEST['token'] )){
             if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){ $response = "0";
             } else {
                $_SESSION['token'] = "";
                $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
                $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
                $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
                $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
                $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
                $select  = $_REQUEST['select'];
                $selectTwo  = $_REQUEST['selectTwo'];
                $selectThree  = $_REQUEST['selectThree'];
                $selectFour  = $_REQUEST['selectFour'];
                $radio = $_REQUEST['radio'];
                $checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox'];
                $switch = $_REQUEST['switch'];
                switch (true){
                case !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL):
                      $response = "<p style='color:red'>Invalid Email Address!</p>";
                break;
                default:
                $to = "support@loaidesign.co.uk";
                $subject = "New Message From: $name";
                $message = "Name: $name <br/>
                            Number: $number <br/>
                            Date: $date <br/>
                            Select: $select <br/>
                            Select2: $selectTwo <br/>
                            Select3: $selectThree <br/>
                            Select4: $selectFour <br/>
                            Radio: $radio <br/>
                            Checkbox: $checkbox <br/>
                            Switch: $switch <br/>
                            Email: $email <br/>
                            Message: $message";
                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: '."support@loaidesign.co.uk" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n";
                $params = '-f support@loaidesign.co.uk';
                $mailed = (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
                if( isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])){ $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
                } else {
                  $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
                }
             break;
             }
             echo $response;
             }
          } else {
          echo "Error";
          }
       ob_flush();
       die();

   }
?>
```

**Contact form HTML:**

```
<!--Contact Form-->
            <?php $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); $_SESSION['token'] = $token;?>
            <form id="contactForm" class="validate" name="contactForm" action="contact.php"  method="post">
               <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
               <input name="ajax" type="hidden" value="1">

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Your Name</p>
                  <input name="name" class="name required fullname" autocomplete="off">
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Email Address</p>
                  <input  name="email" type="email" class="email required" autocomplete="off">
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Message</p>
                  <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="required min3"></textarea>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Phone Number</p>
                  <input name="number" class="hasIcon" autocomplete="off">
                  <i class="form-icon icon-phone"></i>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Time</p>
                  <input name="time" class="mask-time hasIcon" autocomplete="off">
                  <i class="form-icon icon-clock"></i>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Date</p>
                  <input name="date" class="required date calendar hasIcon" autocomplete="off">
                  <i class="form-icon icon-calendar"></i>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p class="inline">Date Selected:</p>
                  <input class="selectedDate inline"></input>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Dropdown Menu</p>
                  <select name="select" class="select required" data-placeholder="Choose an option">
                     <option value=""></option>
                     <option value="DropdownA">DropdownA</option>
                     <option value="DropdownB">DropdownB</option>
                  </select>
               </fieldset>  

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Dropdown Menu - Searchable</p>
                  <select name="selectTwo" class="select-search" data-placeholder="Choose an option">
                     <option value=""></option>
                     <option value="DropdownA">DropdownA</option>
                     <option value="DropdownB">DropdownB</option>
                  </select>
               </fieldset> 

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Multi Options Dropdown Menu</p>
                  <select name="selectThree" class="select multi-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" data-placeholder="Choose an option">
                     <option value=""></option>
                     <optgroup label="Section One">
                        <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
                        <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
                     </optgroup>
                     <optgroup label="Section Two">
                        <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
                        <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
                        <option>Drop Down Option C</option>
                        <option>Drop Down Option D</option>
                     </optgroup>
                  </select>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset>
                  <p>Multi Options Dropdown Menu - Min 2 &amp; Max 3</p>
                  <select name="selectFour" class="select multi-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1"  min="2" max="3">
                     <option value=""></option>
                     <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
                     <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
                     <option>Drop Down Option A</option>
                     <option>Drop Down Option B</option>
                  </select>
               </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="checkbox">
                  <p>Checkboxs:</p>
                  <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionA" class="required"><span class="checked-icon"><span></span></span><span>Option A</span></label>
                  <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="OptionB" class="required"><span class="checked-icon"><span></span></span><span>Option B</span></label>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset class="radio">
                  <p>Radios:</p>
                  <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="male" class="required"><span class="checked-icon"><span></span></span><span>Male</span></label>
                  <label><input name="radio" type="radio" value="female" class="required"><span class="checked-icon"><span></span></span><span>Female</span></label>
               </fieldset>

               <fieldset class="switch">
                  <p>Switch:</p>
                  <label><input name="switch" type="checkbox" value="On"><span><span></span></span></label>
               </fieldset>

               <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Add only relevant code to your question. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You mean only add the HTML for the dropdown? I just thought adding it all might help to understand the full structure

Comment: Select3 and Select4 have no option values setup. Change them to <option value="Dropdown A">Drop Down Option A</option>

Comment: There has to be a value for each option?

Comment: @Leo Yes. Otherwise they will be blank.

Comment: but they worked without it, I.e is only showed the last selection

Answer (score 4):

To get it work, you should specify in your HTML not `name="selectFour"` but `name="selectFour[]"`

EDIT: PHP side, you can exploit the $_REQUEST['selectFour'] as an array.

EDIT: So maybe, you can use implode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: hum, that's weird, I tried it using your example. Maybe have a look on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886240/multi-select-php

Comment: And by the way, you DON'T need to specify a value to each <OPTION>, it will take by default the value between the <option></option> tag.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that wasn't the problem.

Comment: I suggest maybe you should use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST.
I tried it with $_POST.
POST is just an easier way to exploit post forms.

Comment: Just changed them all to POST but same problem :/

Comment: I took what you posted, and theire is no problem adding "implode" and the [].

`Name: a 
Number: 1234567 
Date: fazifjo 
Select: DropdownA 
Select2: DropdownB 
Select3: Drop Down Option A,Drop Down Option B,Drop Down Option C,Drop Down Option D 
Select4: Drop Down Option A,Drop Down Option B 
Radio: female 
Checkbox: OptionA 
Switch: On`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55273/discussion-between-leo-and-d3cima).

Comment: I tried to add [] - the submission shows: Select3: Array 
Select4: Array

Comment: that means select3 is an array. Use `implode(",", $selectThree);` instead of just `$selectThree;`