# php saving multi select tags to a text file

Tags: php, file, select, tags, save

I have 3 select tags inside a form :

```
    <form   id="transactions" method="POST">
        <select name="Markets">
          <option value="Asia_cnl">Asia</option>
          <option value="Europe_mct">Europe</option>
          <option value="America_sth">South America</option>
            ...etc  
        </select>
```

Selecting an option from "Markets" will populate the second slect tag "Circuits". Let's say the user selects option 'Asia':

```
        <select name="Circuits">
          <option value="SSyoung">SSyoung</option>
          <option value="Weytang">Weytang Corp.</option>
          <option value="Anushi">Anushi Media inc.</option>
            ...etc  
        </select>
```

Selecting an option from "Circuits" will load a last select tag "ActivePartners":

```
        <select name="ActivePartners">
          <option value="id_of_partner_1">Partner1</option>
          <option value="id_of_partner_2">Partner2<option>
          <option value="id_of_partner_3">Partner3</option>
            ...etc  
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update List"/>
        </form>
```

The user will delete some values in "ActivePartners" and must save the result to a text file as follow:

- file content  : all remaining options of "ActivePartners"
- file name     : (the selected text of "Circuits").txt
- DIrectory     : /path1/..etc/(the selected text of "Markets")

how can I handle this in php?

Black smoke is out of my head and I am gratefull to any answer to have an 'abemus script! :-)'

Answer (score 0):

First change the form field name value. After submitting data it store in `$_POST` variable so you can track the data with  **`$_POST['markets']`, `$_POST['circuits']`, `$_POST['activePartners']`** then

```
$target_file = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_POST['markets']." ".$_POST['circuits']." ".$_POST['activePartners']."\n";
fwrite($target_file , $txt);
fclose($target_file);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.This will just save each selected option from each select tag in a line and save it into "newfile.text". Therefore my need is to save all data of "activePartners" in a file named ' the selected option of "Circuits" ' in a folder named 'the selected option of "Markets" '.  I am free to change the structure of the html but the requested saving rules are these. To be more clear the first select refers to folder , the second refers to files inside this and the third select is data from a selected file.

Comment: For multiple select from single select option you may see this [Multiple Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886240/multi-select-php)

Comment: Ok I got it by adding a hidden input field which keep track of the path and the file name . Now what will be the way to save all options of "ActivePartners"  to a text file? do I have to iterate through all of them or is there a shorter way?. As I mentioned the path is already fixed in a hidden input value named "file_path" inside the form.